# Hardware Info software (or speedfan) messed up battery calibration

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, calibration

Running Windows 10 Education on my HP 14-ab048tx, I recently used some hardware hardware info software (including hwinfo and msi afterburner) and also speedfan. I did not change any kind of setting in any of these. Now everything is uninstalled. However, my battery calibration is messed up.

So here's what happened: After boot, battery stayed at 100% forever. So I rebooted. Now the battery is properly showing. Now, if charge my laptop to 100%, then the battery again gets stuck to 100% and never comes down. Again restart, and the battery jumps down properly.

Please help, I'm feeling super stupid about installing crap.

EDIT: For clarity, the question is "How to recalibrate the battery?" Also, Ubuntu shows the battery level properly (I dual boot) and it is a new laptop (3 weeks)

Comment: BTW, found a bunch of resources just googling "recalibrate laptop battery", like: http://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/.  This video is by HP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YqzTmqMcjg

Comment: I already tried the how to geek solution, I'll try the HP one when I get home. Thanks!